# GraphicsPath.AddString not as clear as Graphics.DrawString

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, system.drawing

My text and font looks good for most of my application; however, when I do .DrawPath() and the path has a string / text in the GraphicsPath it always looks fussy or blurry.

Can someone tell me how to get the .DrawPath with a string in to look as nice as a GrahpicsPath.DrawString?

```
   //Bay Symbol
   dc.DrawImage(Symbols.GetSymbol(SymbolType.Bay, (i + 1).ToString()), (x + (wPx / 2)) - 10, Constants.ELEVATION_START_Y - 35);




      public static Bitmap GetSymbol(SymbolType symType, string text = "", bool attachLeg = true)
        {
            var sym = new Bitmap(50, 50);
            sym.SetResolution(150, 150);
            using (Graphics dc = Graphics.FromImage(sym))
            {
                dc.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                switch (symType)
                {

                  //code removed for clarity

                    case SymbolType.Bay:
                        dc.DrawPath(ShopDrawing.Pens.GetSymbolPen(), CreateBaySymbol(text));
                        if (attachLeg)
                            AttachSymbolLeg(dc, Constants.BAY_SYMBOL);
                        break;
                };
                dc.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default;

                return sym;
            }
        }



       internal static GraphicsPath CreateBaySymbol(string text = "")
        {
            GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();

            myPath.AddRectangle(Constants.BAY_SYMBOL);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) { Util.AddStringToPath(myPath, text); }

            return myPath;
        }

      internal static void AddStringToPath(GraphicsPath path, string text)
        {
            var textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, Constants.DETAIL_BOX_FONT);

            float centerX = (path.GetBounds().Width / 2) - (textSize.Width / 2),
                  centerY = (path.GetBounds().Height / 2) - (textSize.Height / 2);

            //Add the string to the path.
            path.AddString(text,
                                Constants.DETAIL_BOX_FONT.FontFamily,
                           (int)Constants.DETAIL_BOX_FONT.Style,
                                Constants.DETAIL_BOX_FONT.Size,
                                new PointF(centerX + 2, centerY + 2),
                                StringFormat.GenericDefault)
```

Symbols = a symbol that numbers each part of the elevation below. You can see how the numbering will start at 1 then 2 then 3 and so on.

Here is an snapshot that shows how all the font / text looks good, as in the numbers for the width and height, but the numbering inside the symbols look horrible.

[image: Graphics DrawPath With Text Is Blurry]

Comment: You like ClearType, many users do.  You can't get it from GraphicsPath, only from DrawText().

Comment: @HansPassant's comment is actually the exact answer here.